# Impossible to install python3 matplotlib.pyplot module with pip3 in Gitlab CI

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am part of a Gitlab python3 project where we are trying to install continuous integration thanks to the file .gitlab-ci.yml.

I am trying to install python3 and all the modules that we need, in order to execute a python test script.

I succeeded in installing python3 thanks to apk with the following command.

```
- apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y python3
```

I first need to install pandas, this is working well.

Next, I am trying to install the module matplotlib.pyplot, but it seems impossible, this command does not work:

```
- pip3 install matplotlib.pyplot
Collecting matplotlib.pyplot
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pyplot 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pyplot
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: You cannot install `pyplot` on its own. `pip install matplotlib` will install matplotlib.

Comment: I have successfully installed matplotlib. However when it wanted to run matplotlib.pyplot, it throws an error saying pyplot is not a part of matplotlib library

Comment: Feel free to show the complete error you obtain.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date.py", line 9, in <module>
    plt.pyplot.plot(x, y)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'`

Comment: It's `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then `plt.plot(x,y)`.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Classic [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info).